# Xcode C++ extern variable linker error

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I am learning to code in C++ and am working in Xcode9.1 on OS X 10.13.1. While trying to understand the use of keyword extern, I encountered the problem that the following code:

```
extern int foo;
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    foo = 7;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

results in a linker error when run:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure why the linker cannot find `foo` despite the definition being the first line in `main`.

Thanks very much for looking into my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker cannot find `foo`, because it's not defined anywhere. By declaring `extern int foo`', you're telling the linker that the definition is somewhere else. Remove `extern`, or define `foo` somewhere where the linker can find it.

Have a look at this [example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable#Example_.28C_programming_language.29).

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I thought the example given in your link (specifically file 1) is essentially the same as my code. In my `main` I wrote `foo = 7;`, shouldn't that be a definition?

Comment: I am starting to understand your solution. My original impression was that the line `extern int foo` was enough to serve as a declaration for the variable `foo`. But it looks like it does not actually make the variable. To make my code work I will have to declare `int foo` outside `main`. It seems pointless to do this in one file at first because declaring `foo` outside `main` gives it the file scope anyway, so why bother with `extern`? Turns out `extern` is used as a header statement so that any other file that `#include`s  the `extern`ed variable can use it without declaration.